# Import error when trying to execute a python script from C++ in Visual Studio 2013-15

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently working with Keras for a gesture recognition project.
So I installed Anaconda and Python 2.7 and I made some script that work well with Spyder.

After this, I wanted to use them from my main software that is a Visual Studio 2015 C++ project.
So I use "python.h" for this but I have **import problem**.

**For example, if I try to execute this code :**

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue;         // Initialize the Python Interpreter

Py_Initialize(); 

FILE *fd =  fopen("test.py","r");

PyFile_FromString("test.py", "r");

PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject),"test.py", 1);   //file before returning.    

Py_Finalize();

cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;    
_getch();
```

**This is what I will get as an output :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>  
from numpy import numpy 

ImportError: cannot import name numpy 

Press any key to exit
```

**And here is "test.py" :**

```
from time import time,ctime 

from numpy import np 

np.random.seed(1337) 

//No need to add more code for this example 

print ('Today is',ctime(time()))
```

I am still a beginner in Python so I see that there is some lib missing but I don't understand why it work in Spyder but not here.

Thanks for your attention !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. In fact I had two pythons versions on my computer and Visual Studio took the wrong one.